# Assembly Program for summing integers

Tags: assembly, mips

Basically I'm writing a program that will add the sum of numbers inputtted together.. here is my code, it is giving me an error under main.. If you post an answer and find whats wrong, could you help by putting up the new code ?? Thank you.. Edit: ERROR MESSAGE

error spim: (parser) Label is defined for the second time on line 5 of file C:/Users/peter/Desktop/Running Sums.asm main

```
    .data
str: .asciiz    "Enter a integer:"
str2: .asciiz   "Sum ="
.text
main:
li $a0,0    #sum = 0
loop:
li $v0,4    #print string
la $a0,str
syscall

li,$v0,5    #Take input
syscall
beq $v0,$0,done #if zero was input end and display sum

add $v0,$0,$v0  #sum = sum + input
 j     loop     #Jump to input another number
done:
li  $v0,4       #print string
la  $a0,str2
syscall
li $v0,1        #print sum
move    $a0,$s0
syscall
.end
```

Comment: Please post the error message too.

Comment: For starters, `li,$v0,5 ` has an extra comma.

Comment: error spim: (parser) Label is defined for the second time on line 5 of file C:/Users/peter/Desktop/Running Sums.asm
  main:

Comment: this is literally straight from the book i'm not sure why this is incorrect..

Comment: It is more helpful if you edit and update your question with more information, like that error message, so that people trying to help don't have to search through comments.

Comment: Maybe the book isn't very good? What book is it? Have you tried assembling again with Jesters correction applied? Also, is this the entire assembler source code file, or have you trimmed some off?

Comment: computer organization and design 5th ed

Comment: Did you copy it by hand? It's broken in multiple other places.

Comment: I'm unsure that jester pointed out an issue.. when I updated with his suggestion just another error message came up, the error that i'm concerned with is in the main body of the message

Comment: unfortunately I did copy it by hand, let me see if I can post a screen i checked it multiple times but hey..

Comment: @user3248558 : why not copy and paste it? Please don't post a screenshot of code.

Comment: it isn't copy and paste.. lol i can't post the screen anyways not enough reputation..

Comment: so many sharks telling me how to make this more helpful to you guys, but nobody to actually help :(:( this is all the information available

Comment: @user3248558 : The problem is that by copying it by hand you introduced problems that don;t even make it compilable. You should simply highlight your code and then paste the code inside your question (via editing). You don't need to paste a screenshot, that is useless. We just want to see EXACTLY what code you are using. That is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct working code is:

```
    .data
str: .asciiz    "Enter a integer:"
str2: .asciiz   "Sum ="
.text
main:
li $s0,0    #sum = 0
loop:
li $v0,4    #print string
la $a0,str
syscall

li $v0,5    #Take input
syscall
beq $v0,$0,done #if zero was input end and display sum

add $s0,$s0,$v0  #sum = sum + input
 j     loop     #Jump to input another number
done:
li  $v0,4       #print string
la  $a0,str2
syscall
li $v0,1        #print sum
move    $a0,$s0
syscall
.end
```

Either the book is wrong, or you copied it wrong.

Comment: He says he is copying it by hand.

Comment: Then he can't copy by hand :)

Comment: sorry about my horrible copying by hand skills!! and thank you so much jester :):):) hero of the year

Comment: jester, i'm still getting the main error code.. i'm using qtspim

Comment: Ok, got qtspim v 9.1.5 to install, the code works (except it has no ending so faults at the end).